# android studio 3.0 device file explorer "open with"

Tags: android-studio, android-device-explorer

I open a file once and choose a wrong "open with" option. 
How can I get it to ask me again or use another option?
I tried "right click" with no success.
Thank!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Changing file association in android studio project explorer:**

**Go to Settings >> Editor >> File types**

[image: Settings >> Editor >> File Types]

Switch between recognized file types to find your file extension *(example: *.txt)* or you can directly type it to find results quickly then remove it *(red minus sign in the right)*. Now try to open that file again it should open *"open with.."* dialog for you again.

---

**Edit: after I reviewed your tag, I realized you wanted to open a file from android device explorer. It's almost the same process:**

**Go to Menu >> Windows >> Preferences >> General >> Editor >> File associations**

[image: Android device explorer file association]

Comment: do you know how to do that in Andoid studio 3.1.4 i do not have a menue Menu >> Windows >> Preferences >> General >> Editor >> File associations but i still want to open sqlite db with sqlite browser in linux

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I saw the comment and wanted to check it out but I forgot! I hope you already figured it out but just in case someone else needed to see this the preferences after the update are located in the File menu at the top then go to Editor >> File Types.

Answer (score 0):

in android studio dolphin you must open the file in android studio, click the file name tab on top (same place where you see your class's names) then select `associate with file type` as you can see on image below:

[image: print]